# Get/set video resolution when capturing image

Tags: winapi, video, directshow, video-capture, image-capture

I'm capturing images from my webcam with some code that mainly bases on this: [Using the Sample Grabber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#example_code).

Here I only get the default resolution of 640x480 while the connected camera is able to show more (other capture applications show a bigger resolution).

So, how can I:

1. retrieve the list of available resolutions
2. set one of these resolutions so that the captured image comes with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IAMStreamConfig` interface lists capabilities and lets you select resolution of interest. enumerating media types on an unconnected yet pin will list you specific media types (amd resolutions) the camera advertises as supported.

More on this (an links from there):

- [Video recording resolution using DirectShow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305387/video-recording-resolution-using-directshow/14305455#14305455)
- [Video Capture output always in 320x240 despite changing resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213574/video-capture-output-always-in-320x240-despite-changing-resolution/8216359#8216359)

Comment: Thanks! The MSDN-links mentioned in these posting amazingly tell me something about "deprecated API". Seems like MS has changed their interfaces again :-( But what is the current, preferred method of capturing images from a camera?

Comment: Yes it has been saying this for years already but it is still how you are to do it.