# How to capture 8MP still image from a Microsoft LifeCam programatically?

Tags: c#, webcam, directshow, jpeg

I have a Microsoft LifeCam that is capable of capturing 8MP (3840 x 2160) still jpg images.

Using the software that comes with the LifeCam when you switch to this mode then video capture is disabled.  It is intended for still photos only.  Video capture only goes up to 1280 x 720.

I can't see how to get access to the functionality using any method other than the supplied software.  When inspecting the capture device in GraphEdit there is only 1 pin (called "capture") and it only supplies video.

How can I access this functionality (preferably using C#)?

Comment: BTW what is the model exactly?

Comment: @RomanR. It's a Microsoft LifeCam Studio

Answer (score 0):

DirectShow is intended for video capture (streaming video), not stills. For stills you need to use different API: [Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

My understanding is that highest resolution is achieved using post-processing, such as superresolution and interpolation, and this mode is not available through streaming video driver.

The spec says it's 5MP only. WIA (and TWAIN) driver availability might be subject to operating system version. Due to USB bandwidth limits maximal resolution - even non-interpolated - can be limited to compressed video formats. This post - [Can't make IAMStreamConfig.SetFormat() to work with LifeCam Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383372/cant-make-iamstreamconfig-setformat-to-work-with-lifecam-studio) - enumerates modes and shows that this model supports up to Full HD (1920x1080) resolutions.